# Incorrect equals warning via PMD

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, nullreferenceexception, pmd

For the following code

```
boolean changed = null == oldValue? oldValue != newValue : !oldValue.equals(newValue);
```

I get the PMD warning: "Use equals() to compare object references". But if I follow this proposal, I'll get a NPE. Is it a bug of PMD rule or my programming style is simply bad?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just change it a little bit:

```
boolean changed = null == oldValue ? newValue != null : !oldValue.equals(newValue);
```

Comment: No prob. Happy coding :-)